# Android custom view is offset when while moving

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-view, mobile-development

I'm trying to move a custom view that is in my main activity with a single touch input, however the x/y coordinates for the event are offset due to the action bar.

[GIF of problem](https://really.neato.site/data/G9qot4N7hJJLeyMZ.gif)

I'm trying to find a way to negate the size of the action bar to the y coordinate but nothing seems to be working. I've subtracting the difference in the parent view and my custom view's size from the y coordinate `getRootView().getHeight() - getHeight()` but the value is incorrect.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The custom view:

```
public class SampleView extends View {

    private Paint paint;
    private Path path = new Path();

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public SampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

        switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                path.moveTo(x, y);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                path.lineTo(x, y);
                break;
            }
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

I haven't touched my MainActivity, but have added in the XML for activity_main my custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.caseyweed.sample.MainActivity">

    <com.caseyweed.sample.SampleView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getX()` and `getY()` instead of `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` if you want coordinates relative to the view instead of the device screen coordinates.